# Find the maximum width and length of a swimming pool under these conditions

Tags: problem-solving, area, word-problem

"A 1x1 metre tile costs £45.00. A garden owner has £900 (for tiles) and wants to build a new swimming pool with the base of the pool tiled, as well as the sides. The pool is one metre deep and is twice as long as it is wide. What is the maximum width/length that the pool can be?"

So essentially, we are looking for a rectangle where we tile the area inside the rectangle, as well as the perimeter. How would this question be set up given the constraints mentioned? Hope this is clear!

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's say the pool is $x$ metres wide. It is given that it is twice as long, hence its length is $2x$.

This suffices to find the total area that must be covered as a function of $x$.

The sides of the pool are $4$ rectangles of width $1$. Two of them have length $x$, and the other $2$ have length $2x$. So,

$$\text{Sides Area}=1\cdot x+1\cdot x+1\cdot 2x+1\cdot 2x=6x \space [m^2]$$

The floor has length $2x$ and width $x$, meaning its area is:

$$\text{Floor Area}=2x\cdot x=2x^2 \space [m^2]$$

In total, the area which the tiles should cover is:

$$\text{Area}=\text{Sides Area}+\text{Floor Area}=2x^2+6x \space [m^2]$$

We know that the cost for a $1\times 1$ metre tile is $45$£, implying the cost as a function of $x$ would be:

$$\text{Cost}(x)=45(2x^2+6x)=90x^2+270x$$

The gardener only has $900$£, so we need this cost to be below that:

$$90x^2+270x\leq 900 \implies x^2+3x\leq 10 \implies x^2+3x-10 \leq 0 \implies (x+5)(x-2) \leq 0$$
$$\implies (x+5\leq 0 \space \text{and} \space x-2 \geq 0) \space \text{or} \space (x+5\geq 0 \space \text{and} \space x-2 \leq 0)$$
$$\implies x \geq -5 \space \text{and} \space x\leq 2 \implies -5\leq x\leq 2$$

$x$ represents length, so more strictly $0<x\leq 2$.

Thus, the maximum width is $2$, and the maximum length is $2\cdot 2=4$.

Comment: You could obviously also solve by noticing he can only pay for 20 tiles, and check how many tiles there would be for widths of 1 and 2, but this solution works better in more complicated cases.